# Java - Learning Stacks using a String Sentence

Tags: java, string, stack

I have to take a sentence whatever it is and put each word into a stack and then print it out backwards. So "This is a sentence" would become "sihT si a ecnetnes". I have traced the code with examples like "a b c", and other things and can't figure out what I am missing to get this to work.

My Issues -

1. Can't get the last word to go through the stack because it's based on the space (-1) and once that's give the loop exits.
2. How to take the stack and print it out where the sihT is showing first instead of last and the rest of the sentence follows.

Output:
Phrase - This is a sentence
Phrase Length - 18
Count - 0
Space - 4

Phrase - is a sentence
Phrase Length - 13
Count - 1
Space - 2

Phrase - a sentence
Phrase Length - 10
Count - 2
Space - 1

Phrase - sentence
Phrase Length - 8
Count - 3
Space - -1

a si sihT

Count 3
                           Enter a Phrase or Quit (XXX):

Code:

```
    public class StackClassDriver
    {
       public static void main(String[] args)
       {
    //local constants
    final String QUIT = "XXX"; // Sentinel Value for Quitting

    //local variables
    String Phrase;   // User Input for sentence
    int Count;   // Initalize count to zero
    int Space;  // Initalize First Space
    char Test;
    CharStackClass Stack = new CharStackClass();

    /**************************/

    System.out.print ("Enter Sentence: ");
    Phrase = Keyboard.readString ();

    //WHILE (phrase is not the quit value)
    while (!Phrase.equalsIgnoreCase(QUIT))
    {
        //find position of the first space
        Space = Phrase.indexOf(" ");

        // Initalize count to 1
        Count = 0;

        //WHILE(a space was found)
        while (Space != -1)
        {
            // Test output
            System.out.print ("\n\n");
            System.out.println ("Phrase - " + Phrase);
            System.out.println("Phrase Length - " + Phrase.length());
            System.out.println ("Count - " + Count);
            System.out.println ("Space - " + Space);

            for (int Pos = 0; Pos <= Space; Pos++)
            {
                //convert first word to char
                Test = Phrase.charAt(Pos);

                Stack.push(Test);
            }

            //remove the first word and space from the phrase
            Phrase = Phrase.substring(Space + 1);

            //Add 1 to count
            Count ++;

            //find position of the first space
            Space = Phrase.indexOf(" ");

        }//END WHILE

        // Test output
        System.out.print ("\n\n");
        System.out.println ("Phrase - " + Phrase);
        System.out.println("Phrase Length - " + Phrase.length());
        System.out.println ("Count - " + Count);
        System.out.println ("Space - " + Space);

        System.out.print ("\n\n");

        while (!Stack.isEmpty())
        //for (int Pos = 0; Pos < Count; Pos++)
        {

            //return value at top of stack
            Test = Stack.peek( );

            Test = Stack.pop ();

            System.out.print (Test);

        }

        //Clear Screen
        System.out.print("\n\n\n\n");

        System.out.println("Count " + Count);

        //Input phrase or quit value
        System.out.print(Util.setLeft (27, "Enter a Phrase or Quit (XXX): "));
        Phrase = Keyboard.readString();

        }//END WHILE

      }

      }

      public class CharStackClass
      {
      private char stack [];
      private int stackSize;
      private int top;

      public CharStackClass()
      {
      //local constants

      //local variables

     /**************************/

     stackSize = 50;
     stack = new char[stackSize];
     top = 0;

     }
     public CharStackClass(int size)
     {
     //local constants

    //local variables

    /**************************/

    stackSize = size;
    stack = new char[stackSize];
    top = 0;

    }
    public void push(char num)
    {
    //local constants

    //local variables

    /**************************/

    stack[top] = num;
    top++;
    }
    public char pop()
    {
    //local constants

    //local variables
    char temp;

    /**************************/

    top--;
    temp = stack[top];
    return temp;
    }
    public char peek()
    {
    //local constants

    //local variables

    /**************************/

    return stack[top -1];
    }
    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
    //local constants

    //local variables

    /**************************/

    return top == 0;
    }
    public boolean isFull()
    {
    //local constants

    //local variables

    /**************************/

    return top == stackSize;
    }


    }
```

Comment: From which package do you get the Keyboard class?

Comment: It's a keyboard util. I'll see if I can upload that.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this quite a bit. Consider this pseudo-code

```
pos = 0
while not end of string
    if string[pos] is space
        while stack is not empty
            print stack.pop()
        end-while
        print ' '  // space between words
    end-if
    else
        stack.push(string[pos])
    end-else
    pos = pos + 1
end-while
// at this point, there might be another word on the stack,
// because there was no space at the end of the sentence
while stack is not empty
    print stack.pop()
end-while
```